# Changing ListView Template/View

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am wondering how to change a ListView's view or template (not %100 sure what it is called). The process that I am currently using is bypassing the listview's built in functions to Insert, Update, and Delete. Here is an example of my update:

```
protected void LV_Products_ItemUpdating(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int fail = DatabaseInteraction.UpdateJobProducts(Int32.Parse(JobProductKeyLabel.Text), Int32.Parse(JobIDLabel.Text), ProductDate, ProductsDDL.SelectedItem.ToString(), ProductQuantity, ProductRate);

    //Check to see if the insert was successful. No message if yes, but alert user if no.
    if (fail == -1)
    {
        AlertMessage("Update failed.");
    }

    //We need to cancel the "actual" insert now so it doesn't fail.
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

The reason that I use `e.Cancel = true;` is because it will cancel the actual Update and allow my custom update to take place.

The process that I undergo to update is as follows:

-Click Edit button in ListView

-ListView changed to "Edit View"

-Make changes to record

-Click Update (this is the event handler)

So once I have done my update (which works perfectly fine.) My listview stays in the Update "view". So how can I change the view of my listview from the code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change back from the Edit view I actually changed the Update button in the listview to a Cancel button. So in the event handle of the cancel button did the insert work. And the cancel button automatically changes the listview back to the original format.